# Probability for firing shots independently and at random into a circular target

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A circular target of unit radius is divided into four annular zones with outer radii $1/4, 1/2, 3/4,$ and $1$, respectively:

- Suppose $10$ shots are fired independently and at random into the target.

  - If $5$ shots land inside the disk of radius $1/2$, find the probability that at least one is in the disk of radius $1/4$.

My answer:
$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{5}\binom{5}{k}\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)^k\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^{5-k}}{\displaystyle\binom{10}{5}\left(\frac14\right)^5\left(\frac34\right)^5} = 1.275e-2$

Author Hoel,Port,Stone provided answer
$\displaystyle 1- \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{5}$.

Whose answer is correct $?$. My answer or author's answer $?$.

Comment: I have removed  the first part of the question because it is irrelevant your actual query on the post.

Comment: Authors answer is correct

Comment: Your denominator should be $\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}\left(\frac{1}{16}\right)^k\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^{5-k}=\left(\frac4{16}\right)^5$. Then it agrees with the outcome of the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of any circle is **linearly** proportional to the square of its  radius (i.e. $\pi r^2$).  So, the area of the circle whose radius equals $~\dfrac{1}{2}~$ is equal to $(4) \times ~$ the area of the circle whose radius equals $~\dfrac{1}{4}.$

This implies that for any *shot* that lands in the larger circle, the probability is $~\dfrac{3}{4}~$ that the *shot* is not in the smaller circle.  Another way of saying the same thing is that if you choose any random number $x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 4$, then the probability that $1 \leq x \leq 4$ is $~\dfrac{3}{4}.$

Therefore, the probability that all $(5)$ shots miss the smaller circle is

$$\left[\frac{3}{4}\right]^5.$$

This supports the problem composer's answer.

Comment: This seems, the probability is independent of number of shots fired.

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo Yes, the probability is independent of number of shots fired.  Suppose, for example, that you were given that $(100)$ shots were fired, instead of only $(10)$ shots.  Suppose further, that you were given that $(95)$ of those $(100)$ shots landed outside the disk of radius $(1/2)$ and $(5)$ shots landed inside the disk of radius $(1/2)$.  Then, the analysis would be **identical** and $(95)$ of the shots should be **ignored**.  That is, if a shot landed outside the disk of radius $(1/2)$ then it necessarily also landed outside the disk of radius $(1/4)$.